# Tracking thread failures

Tags: java, kotlin

I have an HTML which is output (displaying the results of the threads) and displayed after all threads complete (I wait for completion using a join)

Sometimes individual threads can have exceptions.

- If I don't have any exceptions in any threads, i want to display the HTML in my browser.
- If I do have an exception in all threads then I want to NOT display the HTML
- If I have an exception in some but not all threads then I want TO display the HTML

What's the easiest way (least amount of code) to implement something that can track if a thread has failed or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CompletableFuture` for this purpose, example:

```
val future1: CompletableFuture<String> = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync {
    println("This is your thread 1 code")
    "<html><head><title>"
}

val future2: CompletableFuture<String> = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync {
    println("This is your thread 2 code")
    if (Random().nextBoolean()) throw RuntimeException("Failed")
    "Title!</title></html></head>"
}

future1.thenCombine(future2, {result1, result2 -> result1 + result2}).whenComplete { s, throwable ->
    if (throwable != null) {
        println("failed")
    } else {
        println("done with $s")
    }
}
```

And in Kotlin 1.1 you will be able write this code in more readable way:

```
async {
    try {
        val s1 = await(future1)
        val s2 = await(future2)
        println(s1 + s2)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("failed")
    }
}
```